# Debug Assertion failed ! in detectAndDisplay function of face recognition openCv

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to run the program and is building well but not able to debug. Capturing first frame and then giving below error.

I tried to check in debug mode and could figure out that

```
imshow(window_name, frame);
```

[Error !!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1it3K.png)

Here is the **working code** that is copied from OpenCV blog.

```
            #include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
            #include "opencv2/video/video.hpp"
            #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
            #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

            #include <iostream>
            #include <stdio.h>

            using namespace std;
            using namespace cv;

            /** Function Headers */
            void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame);

            /** Global variables */
            String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
            String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
            CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
            CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;
            string window_name = "Capture - Face detection";
            RNG rng(12345);

            /** @function main */
            int main(int argc, const char** argv)
            {
                CvCapture* capture;
                Mat frame;

                //-- 1. Load the cascades
                if (!face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name)) { printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
                if (!eyes_cascade.load(eyes_cascade_name)) { printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };

                //-- 2. Read the video stream
                capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);



                if (capture)
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

                        //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
                        if (!frame.empty())
                        {
                            detectAndDisplay(frame);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
                            break;
                        }

                        int c = waitKey(10);
                        if ((char)c == 'c') { break; }
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            }

            /** @function detectAndDisplay */
            void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame)
            {
                std::vector<Rect> faces;
                Mat frame_gray;

                cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
                equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);

                //-- Detect faces
                face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

                for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
                {
                    Point center(faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5);
                    ellipse(frame, center, Size(faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 4, 8, 0);

                    Mat faceROI = frame_gray(faces[i]);
                    std::vector<Rect> eyes;

                    //-- In each face, detect eyes
                    eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

                    for (size_t j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++)
                    {
                        Point center(faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width*0.5, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height*0.5);
                        int radius = cvRound((eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25);
                        circle(frame, center, radius, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4, 8, 0);
                    }
                }
                //-- Show what you got
                imshow(window_name, frame);
            }
```

Error when value chosen in

```
 capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1)
```

is -1.

I am getting GRey window with no Error.
[imshow with Grey Window, No Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtlNV.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the Platform Toolset from **Visual Studio 2015(v140)** to **Visual Studio 2013(v120)** as in the figure attached. I do not know why but it worked.

[Visual Studio 2015(v140)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAcV7.png)

[Visual Studio 2013(v120)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17PYK.png)

Answer (score 0):

It may happen, if your face ROI, out of frame bounds.
Because you trying to copy this region you getting memory error.

```
if(faces[i].x>=0 && faces[i].y >= 0 && faces[i].x+faces[i].width<frame_gray.cols && faces[i].y+faces[i].height < frame_gray.rows)
{
faceROI=frame_gray(faces[i]);
}
```

Comment: Just add condition checking ROI location for commands like thes Mat faceROI = frame_gray(faces[i]); . So that roi corners be inside frame gray image.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this? Please add one, then I can do rest if needed.

Comment: Which line cause error? When error appears, press "retry", then "break". And check call stack to identify the error line.

Comment: Smorodov However, when I am assigning -1 to the  cvCaptureFromCAM its giving stable window of Capture window but GREY, nothing is shown in it

Comment: ucrtbased.dll!00f73b95() Unknown     ----------

OPEN_CV_TEST.exe!detectAndDisplay(cv::Mat frame) Line 98 ----- C++           

OPEN_CV_TEST.exe!main(int argc, const char * * argv) Line 47 C++

Comment: Can't see GREY window in source above. Can you debug line by line DetectAndDisplay method and check values of all variables?

Comment: I have updated the question with Grey window when value is -1..........---
Well I did the debugging line by line and interesting thing is first frame is captured and imshow works and when code for the second frame it gives the error.